# How do I remove mask off stuff?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I got this grass & I don't know how to make the mask transparent. Basically I just want to see the grass but the cubes are blocking it since it isn't transparent. I also have this tree with the same issue. Just to inform you I am using cycles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a shader like this. If your texture doesn't have alpha channel plug the color to the "Fac" input or you can use a separate mask texture of course.
[image]

Comment: I've does this but it doesn't really make a difference, anything I've done wrong? https://imgur.com/a/Swt5f0i

Comment: Yes, you've done something wrong.:)  Use only one material output, two of them makes no sense. You can use anything instead of the diffuse. https://imgur.com/a/vO6PiD7